Is there a way to get a step function task token from a step that is already running?
I have misconfigured a lambda call within a step function waitForTaskToken pattern, as in
"Payload": {
    "taskToken": "$$.Task.Token",
    "field1": "blah"
}

instead of
"Payload": {
    "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token",
    "field1": "blah"
}

And the value of the task token seems to be lost forever, because I can't find it anywhere. And the step is now hanging as Running. I don't have permissions to terminate the execution, but I have a lambda that accepts a task token and sends task success. How do I get the token now?
AWS CLI get-execution-history doesn't have it, AWS Console doesn't have it in ANY of the inputs or outputs. They all just say "yeah, sure, here is your input to the step, it's  "taskToken": "$$.Task.Token",
Which, as you can imagine, isn't terribly helpful. I expected some way to map execution id and a step to a task token.

Unfortunately, no you cannot look up that Task Token after the fact. Though this is a feature we have heard from customers before.
Depending on whether you set timeouts on the Task or the State Machine, the execution may time out sooner. But if not, it will run up to the 1 year maximum duration. You will probably want to identify someone with StopExecution permissions.
